# Mark entire class thread-safe, thereby avoiding SyncLock in each member

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a class, written in VB, which must be used by multiple threads. I was able to manage this and make it thread-safe by using the `SyncLock` statement inside each member. However, there are many functions in the class and it would be easier if I could just mark the whole class, once. I can’t find any statement in VB that does this. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you simply can't, you have to explicitly design your class to be thread-safe either by making your members immutable or by handling synchronization and avoid thread race conditions as you mentioned you already do.

Comment: Ok thx .. no more comments on this topic I guess I have no other choice .. thx